# Zug - Bewegung - Dativ?

Tags: dative

Ich möchte gerne wissen, warum in dem folgenden Satz überall Dativ ist:

> ..., dass der Zug von einem Gleis abfährt, auf einem Gleis ankommt und auch auf einem Gleis steht.

Ich verstehe, dass etwas auf einem Gleis stehen kann -> keine Bewegung -> Dativ. Aber woher kommt Dativ bei "von einem Gleis/auf einem Gleis" wenn ein Zug ankommt oder abfährt -> das ist doch eine Bewegung, oder??

LG nika

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die "Zweiwege-Präpositionen" sind **an**, **auf**, **hinter**, **neben**, **in**, **über**, **unter**, **vor** und **zwischen**.

Nur bei diesen neun Präpositionen bedeutet Dativ einen Ort, während Akkusativ eine Richtung bezeichnet. Alle anderen Präpositionen stehen immer mit demselben Fall, und es kann dann auch der Dativ eine Richtung bezeichnen und Akkusativ einen Ort.

In anderen Fällen legt schon das Verb fest, ob es sich um einen Ort oder eine Richtung handelt. Viele Verben können nur mit Ort oder mit Richtung verwendet werden, nicht mit beidem.

> dass der Zug von einem Gleis abfährt, auf einem Gleis ankommt und auch auf einem Gleis steht.

**von** steht immer mit Dativ.

**ankommen** erfordert einen Ort, keine Richtung. Man kann nicht "wohin ankommen".

**stehen** erfordert einen Ort, keine Richtung. Man kann nicht "wohin stehen".

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung. Es scheint logisch zu sein. Es bleibt noch eine Frage bestehen: Woher soll man wissen ob ein Verb einen Ort oder eine Richtung erfordert? Manche Verben wie stehen, stellen etc sind klar, aber bei dem erwähnten Verb "ankommen" ist es nicht mehr so offensichtlich. PS. In meiner Muttersprache ist "wohin bist du angekommen?" völlig korrekt:) Vielleicht deswegen habe ich das anders betrachtet.

Comment: Das musst du leider auswendig lernen. Genau wie die Präpositionen, die überhaupt mit einem bestimmten Verb stehen können. Manchmal hängt es sogar von der Bedeutung des Verbs ab, ob Akkusativ oder Dativ verwendet wird: *Thomas steht auf seinem Laster* – Thomas hat einen Lastwagen und steht auf der Ladefläche. *Thomas steht auf sein Laster* – Thomas hat ein Laster (Rauchen oder so) und liebt es ganz doll.

Comment: *Thomas steht auf seine**n** Laster.* – Thomas liebt seinen Lastwagen ganz doll.

Answer (score 4):

Nein. Abfahren ist etwas, das an einem festen Ort passiert. Der Ort, von dem man abfährt, ist kein Ziel einer Bewegung.

Dasselbe gilt für *ankommen*. Ankommen ist ein Ereignis, das an einem festen Ort stattfindet. Ankommen ist grammatisch keine Bewegung.

Beispiele:

> Martha fährt auf einen großen Platz zu.

Das ist eine Bewegung, die auf ein Ziel gerichtet ist. Daher steht das Ziel im Akkusativ.

> Uwe kommt auf einem großen Platz an.

Das Ankommen ist keine Bewegung auf ein Ziel zu. Uwe ist ja schon am Ziel. Er befindet sich dort, und tut dort etwas: Er kommt dort an. Also Dativ.

> Maria fährt von einem großen Platz ab.

Wie kennen das Ziel von Maria gar nicht. Wir kennen nur den Ort, an dem sie etwas tut. Sie fährt von dort ab. Also Dativ.

Comment: "Von" hat doch immer den Dativ, oder wie? Da kommt es nicht auf Richtung oder Ort an.